# python checksum verification of two large files

Tags: python, hashlib

I am trying to create a checksum of two files to compare them.  This is the script I am using:

```
import hashlib
import datetime
f = open('myfile.mov', 'rb')
def checkF(f, block_size=2**20):
...     print datetime.datetime.now()
...     h = hashlib.sha1()
...     while True:
...             data = f.read(block_size)
...             if not data:
...                     break
...             h.update(data)
...     print datetime.datetime.now()
...     return h.digest()
... 
>>> checkF(f)
2012-03-21 09:33:40.704032
2012-03-21 09:33:40.704490
'\xda9\xa3\xee^kK\r2U\xbf\xef\x95`\x18\x90\xaf\xd8\x07\t'
```

Firstly, I'm not familiar with the output.  Is this the string I can use to compare to the other file?  Secondly, running this script on the same file a second time gives a different result.  It seems to be related to how much time has passed between passes. I don't fully understand what's happening here.  Any help would be great.

Comment: try opening and closing the file inside `checkF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reopen the file every time you call checkF, or reset the position of the file pointer with [`f.seek(0)`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek). That's why you get different hashsums: The first one is the hash of the file contents, and all latter ones are hashsums of the empty string (i.e. `da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709`).

To get the hashsum as a hexadecimal string (for human consumption), simply call [`h.hexdigest()`](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) instead of `h.digest()`, which returns the hashsum as a bytestring (more compact, but not human-readable).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> '\xda9\xa3\xee^kK\r2U\xbf\xef\x95`\x18\x90\xaf\xd8\x07\t'.encode('hex')
'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'
```

But you probably want to just use `hexdigest()` instead

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to close file with f.close()
Please put this after calling checkF(f), sometimes python returns unpredictable results if you did'n close file at the end of your program.

Comment: -1 If *any* application (whether Python or not) terminates without closing all its handles, every operating system will predictably close the files. You shouldn't explicitly call `f.close` anyways. Instead, use a context manager.

Comment: Context managers available on python >=2.6, so you recommendation is partially true.